# How can evaluate an expression stored as a string in F#

Tags: .net, f#

I want to do something sort of like this:

```
let x = 5
let y = 10

let expr = Console.ReadLine()

expr
```

Where one might type `"x+y"` in the console to store in expr.

How does one evaluate a statement like this in F#?

Ultimately, I want a user to be able to enter expressions, or a set of rules for a system, on a webpage and have them saved in a database to be applied at appropriate times in an F# library.  I just don't know how to convert the entered string in to a function value in F#.

Thanks for any help you may provide!

Adam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

F# doesn't have eval, as mentioned, but if you can define the grammar, you can utilize the Lex and Yacc implementations in F# (fslex and and fsyacc).

*EDIT:*

As a quick follow up, I know in ocaml you can exploit the interactive console to your users with `ocamlmktop`. I am unsure of an equivalent in F#. This, although, doesn't seem to match what you want with a web interface (correct?).

Comment: Do you know if anyone has defined the grammar for F# for this purpose yet?  Seems like a useful thing, and not something that should be reinvented by everyone who needs it.

Comment: @Adam: Microsoft deliberately closed the interfaces that made this possible specifically to prevent people from using this technique to create competitors to Visual Studio.

Answer (score 5):

I just saw Joh use quotation evaluations on his
[F# for game development page](http://sharp-gamedev.blogspot.com/2008/09/tutorial-10-generic-programming-using.html)

```
      open Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.QuotationEvaluation
      ...
      let mk_gravity scale_func (up: 'Vec): 'Vec =
      let q = <@ let (*) = %scale_func in -9.81 * up @>
      q.Eval()
```

Alternately, if you are after simple math evaluation, you can download Edmonodo's Expression parser and evaluator from his codeplex plage - [Symbolic Differentiation in C#/F#](http://www.codeplex.com/SymbDifferentiation)

Good luck - Jiří

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing out of the box for this.

I'm not sure what your needs are, but you might consider the Dynamic LINQ sample. It has a little parser to generate expression trees, which you can then compile or manipulate. ScottGu talks about it [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx).

While it looks like it is mainly for extending LINQ queries, it acts as a nice parser. We hacked it up to support do/let bindings for a bit more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

F# doesn't have an eval function like Lisp's (AFAIK), if that's what you're wondering. You could build up an expression tree yourself though, based on string input.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can look at [my F# code](https://github.com/0x69/coding-experiments/blob/master/Fsharp/MathEvaluator.fs) which implements math expressions evaluator.